# Community wiki post should also not be used to gain the referrer badges

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

[Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange) has all community posts. I see the following link that should be used to share posts links on various places on the internet that helps you get the Announcer, Booster and Publicist badges. These are identified by the id that get's appended to the sharing link as we all know.

[image: Referrer link]

I guess it's ok to use this on SE sites itself under our own accounts while commenting, in chat and in our own non-wiki post, but including them in wiki post doesn't seem write.

What do you guys say about this behaviour ?

Comment: Why shouldn't you get badges for publicising CW posts?

Comment: The referrer exists as a reward for getting people to the site. It's likely done by post and not just for the whole site because people aren't going to share 'StackOverflow' they're going to share an explicit article. CW posts are part of the SE sites and getting new visitors to the sites is a good thing, regardless of the type of post people come to. Heck, if you could share a Tag Wiki and get people to visit just to look at that then that should still be rewarded because you're getting people to the site.

Comment: @MartinSmith That's not what OP is saying. What he is saying is that people shouldn't use personalized links to other questions in CW posts to gain the publicity badges. Which isn't an issue, as hits coming from SE sites don't count towards the publicity badges anyway.

Comment: @Yannis - You're right.

Comment: I guess people are mis-interpreting my questions and down-voting it. I am not against sharing CW posts. Please read the question carefully.

Comment: I know how down-voting works on meta. But I am confused now. Please tell me why you dis-agree with my view. Even if you dis-agree, the referral link from SO doesn't count to the badges so agreement/disagreement doesn't make sense here. Please let me know your views. And that means you expect the such referrals to be counted towards the badges given.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a non issue, only clicks from *outside the Stack Exchange network* count towards Announcer, Booster and Publicist.

Comment: Thanks I didn't know that.